# Как сделать автоматическое добавление символа в EditText?

Tags: kotlin, android-edittext

Нужны советы, примеры конечно приветствуются, но главная задача понять возможно ли это сделать и как это сделать (возможно некоректное объяснение - неопытность):
Имеется

```
holder.planValue.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%4f", dataList[position].planHa))
dataList[position].haTextWatcher?.let { holder.planValue.removeTextChangedListener(it) }
holder.planValue.filters = arrayOf(DecimalDigitsInputFilter( 4, 4 ))
dataList[position].haTextWatcher = object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {...}
        }
holder.planValue.addTextChangedListener(dataList[position].haTextWatcher)
```

Собственно есть некоторое количество EditText-ов (holder.planValue), у каждого своё полученное значение из бд, например: 38.6900, либо 123.0700. Если же отсутствует, то по дефолту записывается 0.0000. При фокусе на EditText, если значение "0.0000", то выполняется holder.planValue.SelectAll(), после ввода "1234" получаем:

0.0000 => 1234 // ввод блокируется из-за DecimalDigitsInputFilter(4, 4) и ожидает символ '.'

Ввели ".5678"  получаем:
1234 => 1234.5678

**Вопрос: как сделать автоматическое добавление '.' после введение первых 4-ых символов**. Ввели "1471":

0.0000 => 1471.

Ввели "14719063":

0.0000 => 1471.9063

Но при этом, должна быть возможность самому поставить '.', если ввели "13.4600":

0.0000 => 13.4600

И бонусный вопрос: как запретить ввод '0', если это первый символ, то есть нельзя ввести "01.0200"

Comment: Пиши inputFilter

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас займусь

Comment: Может вам просто нужен ввод по маске? Как пример: https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-android

Comment: Благодарю за предложение, как я понимаю, то нужно использовать несколько масок, а через условие их менять? Например, если первый символ '0', то использовать "_.____", если первые 4 символа не содержат '.', то использовать "____.____". Я правильно понял?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собственно добился чего хотел:

1. Если значение равно "0.0000", то при фокусе выделяет весь текст
2. При вводе '.' в пустую строку, или если весь текст выделен : _ || aaaa.bbbb => 0.
3. При вводе '0' ~-~ : _ || aaaa.bbbb => 0.
4. При вводе 4-ых символов 'aaaa' ~-~ : aaaa.bbbb || _ => aaaa.

Надеюсь, начинающим вроде меня будет полезным. Вроде при стирании символов работает адекватно. Критика приветствуется.

```
class ThirdActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_third)

    val editText: EditText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text)
    editText.setText(String.format("%.4f", 0.0))
    editText.filters = arrayOf(DecimalDigitsInputFilter(4,4))
    editText.setOnFocusChangeListener{ _, hasFocus ->
        if(hasFocus && (editText.text.toString() == "0.0000")) editText.setSelectAllOnFocus(true)
        editText.selectAll()
    }
    }

class DecimalDigitsInputFilter(private val digitsBeforeDot: Int, private val digitsAfterDot: Int): InputFilter{

    override fun filter(source: CharSequence?, start: Int, end: Int, dest: Spanned, dstart: Int, dend: Int): CharSequence? {
        val builder = StringBuilder(dest)
        builder.insert(dstart, source)
        val temp = builder.toString()
        val index = temp.indexOf('.')


        return if ( ((temp == "." || temp == "0") && dest.isEmpty()) || ((source == "0" || source == ".") && dest.toString() == "0.0000")){
            "0."
        } else if (temp.length == 4 && !dest.contains('.') && dstart == 3 && dend == 3){
            "$source."
        } else if (index == -1){
            if (temp.length > digitsBeforeDot){
                ""
            } else{ null }
        } else{
            if(temp.substring(0, index).length > digitsBeforeDot || temp.substring(index + 1, temp.length).length > digitsAfterDot){
                ""
            }else{
                null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}